# Group and count returned SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, list

I have two tables `abb` and `abb_click`.

`abb` contains information which object **ident** that's active. `abb_click` contains information from each **student_id** regarding each **ident**.

I "simply" want to count the active **ident** in `abb_click` for a specific **student_id**.

The SELECT below seems to count only the active **ident**s, not taking any concern if the **ident** is in `abb_click`.

You can see the fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7262/1

---

**The result should be:** 
for the student_id 945 - 2 active **ident**s

**Question:** how do I "tweak" the SELECT to count the active **ident**s in table `abb` joined with `abb_click`?

---

```
SELECT t.student_id, number_of_idents
FROM `abb_click` AS t 
  INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT ident, COUNT(ident) as number_of_idents FROM `abb` AS k 
      WHERE k.active = '1' 
      ) AS t3 
    ON t.ident = t3.ident
WHERE t.student_id = '945' 
GROUP BY t.student_id
ORDER BY number_of_idents ASC;
```

**Table `abb`**

```
bid, ident, active
```

**Table `abb_click`**

```
kid, ident, student_id, click
```

**Data to table `abb`**

```
1, 'ma53', 1 
2, 'ma664', 1 
3, 'ma779', 0 
4, 'ma919', 1
```

**Data to table `abb_click`**

```
1, 'ma53', 945, 'E'
2, 'ma53', 945, 'E'
3, 'ma53', 945, 'C'
4, 'ma664', 945, 'C'
5, 'ma664', 945, 'A'
6, 'ma664', 945, 'E'
7, 'ma779', 945, 'A'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do what you want.

```
select student_id, COUNT(distinct ac.ident) as active_idents
from abb_click ac
join abb on abb.ident = ac.ident
where abb.active = 1
--and student_id = 945
group by student_id
```

Comment: Very neat and working just fine (with the extra `AND student_id = 945`). Many thanks for your time and help. Thank you @Sander!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've miss-understood this should work.

```
SELECT abb.*, COUNT(abb_click.id) as total_abb_clicks
FROM abb
INNER JOIN abb_click ON abb_click.ident = abb.ident
WHERE abb.active = 1 && abb_click.student_id = 945 
GROUP BY abb.id
```

--
Edit: Sorry I forgot the student condition.  So this should return:

bid, ident, active, total_abb_clicks
1, 'ma53', 1 , 3
2, 'ma664', 1, 3
4, 'ma919', 1, 1

Comment: Thank you @Camway. Not really the result I wanted but very useful indeed.

Comment: Now seeing the answer I see where you were coming from; I miss understood.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the distinct values of ident and student_id by grouping them and then joining with `abb` and doing the counting:

```
SELECT click.student_id, COUNT(click.ident) as total_abb_clicks
FROM abb
INNER JOIN (select ident, student_id from abb_click group by ident, student_id) click ON click.ident = abb.ident
WHERE abb.active = 1 and click.student_id=945
GROUP BY click.student_id
```

Comment: This is working just fine. Many thanks for your time and help. Thank you @Sami Kuhmonen!